# A partial differential equation with trig functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let $\xi:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function $\xi(x,y,z)$. I have the following PDE:
$$
\cos(\xi)\partial_y\xi = \sin(\xi)\partial_x\xi
$$
which is equivalent to $\tan(\xi)=\xi_y/\xi_x$.

Clearly, $\xi_x = \xi_y = 0$ (where $\partial_i\xi=\xi_i$) is a solution, which would imply $\xi(x,y,z) = \eta(z)$ is only a function of $z$.

**But are there any other solutions? If not, how to *prove* it?**

My thoughts so far: obviously, 
\begin{align}
\xi_x &= \cos(\xi)\\
\xi_y &= \sin(\xi)
\end{align} 
together describe a solution.
We can solve these separately to get:
$$
\xi = 2\arctan(\exp(y+f_1(x,z))\;\;\;\&\;\;\; 
\xi=2\arctan(\tanh([1/2][x+f_2(y,z)]))
$$
respectively. 
This implies that $$
\exp(y+f_1(x,z)) = \tanh([x+f_2(y,z)]/2) $$
Not sure if this line of thinking is useful though.

Comment: A quick way is the hodograph transformation, $x=X(\xi,y)$, whereby $\xi_x=1/X_\xi$ and $\xi_y=-X_y/X_\xi$.  You will get a solution $\xi(x,y)$ defined implicitly.

Comment: @user254433 Thank you for the suggestion. Ultimately my goal is to see under what conditions $\xi = \eta(z)$ is the *only* solution to the equation though, so I'm not sure I want an implicit solution. :)

Comment: It's not the only solution.  $-X_y=\tan\xi$ implies $X(\xi,y,z)=c(\xi,z)-y\tan\xi$ for some $c$.  We can rewrite this as an implicit equation for $\xi(x,y,z)$: $\tan\xi=\frac{x}{f(\xi,z)-y}$.  Choose $f=0$, for example.  You get the solution: $\xi(x,y,z)=-\arctan(x/y)$.

Comment: $(\partial_x, \partial_y) \xi = (\cos(\xi), \sin(\xi))$ describes one solution. $(\partial_x, \partial_y) \xi = \phi \, (\cos(\xi), \sin(\xi))$, for different smooth enough functions $\phi$, describes all solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an expanded version of what I mentioned in the comments.

In case you aren't familiar with the method of characteristics, there is a simple trick for solving this kind of equation: interchange $x$ with $\xi$.  Let $X(u,y,z)$ be the solution of $$u=\xi(X,y,z).$$  To evaluate your PDE $$\xi_y\cos\xi=\xi_x\sin\xi$$ in new variables, differentiate the above equation.  Taking $\partial_u$, it follows that $ 1= \xi_X X_u$, so $\xi_X=1/X_u$, assuming $X_u\neq 0$ of course.  Taking $\partial_y$, we have $0=\xi_XX_y+\xi_y$, so $\xi_y=-X_y/X_u$.  Substituting into your PDE, we get:
$$
-X_y(u,y,z)\cos u =\sin u,
$$
such that $X_y=-\tan u$ for $u\notin \pi (\mathbb Z+1/2)$.  We can write the general solution as $$X(u,y,z)=(f(u,z)-y)\tan u,$$
such that $\xi(x,y,z)$ is found by solving the equation
$$
x=(f(\xi(x,y,z),z)-y)\tan\xi(x,y,z).
$$
Let us rewrite this implicit solution as follows:
$$
\tan\xi(x,y,z)=\frac{x}{f(\xi(x,y,z),z)-y}.
$$
Since $f$ is an arbitrary function, let us choose $f(\xi,z)=g(z)$, for example.  Then we obtain an explicit solution:
$$
\xi(x,y,z)=\arctan\left(\frac{x}{g(z)-y}\right),
$$
where $g$ is an arbitrary function, and $(x,y,z)$ are restricted to domains where the right hand side makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for expanding your comment. Just wondering: is $\tan(\xi)=x(f(\xi,z) - y)^{-1}$ equivalent to $\xi = F(y\cos(\xi) + x\sin(\xi),z)$?

Comment: @user3658307 Your expression should be $\xi=F(x\cos\xi+y\sin\xi,z)$, but yes, except if the denominators don't make sense.  To see this, we have $x=f\tan\xi-y\tan\xi$, or $x\cos\xi +y\sin\xi=f(\xi,z)\sin\xi$.  But $f$ is arbitrary, so $x\cos\xi+y\sin\xi=F(\xi,z)$ for arbitrary $F$, which can be formally inverted to give $\xi=G(x\cos\xi+y\sin\xi,z)$.

Answer (score 1):

Characteristic curves of $0=\sin(ξ)ξ_x-\cos(ξ)ξ_y$ follow the direction field
$$
\frac{dx}{\sin(ξ)}=\frac{dy}{-\cos(ξ)}=\frac{dz}{0}=\frac{dξ}{0}
$$
which means that $\cos(ξ)x+\sin(ξ)y=c_1$, $z=c_2$, $ξ=c_3$ are constant along these curves and the curves are completely characterized by these first integrals. As there are 3 constants for a family of curves in the 3 dimensional graph of $ξ$, there is one parameter too much, that is, there exists a relation $g(c_1,c_2,c_3)=0$ resp. $g(\cos(ξ)x+\sin(ξ)y,z,ξ)=0$ among them.

For example, if $u$ is any differentiable function of $2$ variables, the solution of the implicit equation
$$
ξ=u(\cos(ξ)x+\sin(ξ)y,z)
$$
satisfies the given equation as long as $$(\cos(ξ)y-\sin(ξ)x)\,\partial_1u\ne 1.$$

Comment: I think your first equation has $\cos\xi$ and $\sin\xi$ flipped.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Three times looking and comparing was not enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\cos(ξ)\frac{\partial ξ}{\partial y}- \sin(ξ)\frac{\partial ξ}{\partial x}=0 \tag 1
$$

With the method of characteristics, the set of ODEs for the characteristic curves is :
$$\frac{dy}{\cos(ξ)}=\frac{dx}{-\sin(ξ)}=\frac{dz}{0}=\frac{dξ}{0} \quad\implies\quad dξ=0\quad\text{and}\quad dz=0$$
A first family of characteristic curves comes from $dξ=0 \quad\to\quad ξ=c_1$.

A second family of characteristic curves comes from $\frac{dy}{\cos(c_1)}=\frac{dx}{-\sin(c_1)} \quad\to\quad x\cos(c_1)+y\sin(c_1)=c_2$

A third family of characteristic curves comes from $dz=0 \quad\to\quad z=c_3$.

This is true any $c_1$ and $c_2$ and $c_3$, hence the equation $\Phi(c_1,c_2,c_3)=0$ is true any function $\Phi$ of three variables.
$$\Phi\left(ξ\:,\:x\cos(ξ)+y\sin(ξ)\:,\:z\right)=0$$
Or, on another equivalent form :
$$ξ=F\left(x\cos(ξ)+y\sin(ξ)\:,\:z\right)\tag 2$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function of two variables.

This is the general solution of the PDE $(1)$ expressed on implicit form.

If one want the explicit form $ξ(x,y,z)$, one have to solve $(2)$ for $ξ$. This is not always analytically possible because there is not always a closed form for the roots of the equation $(2)$. This depends on the function $F$.

The function $F$ have to be determined according to some boundary conditions. Since no boundary condition is specified in the wording of the question, we cannot go further.

Nevertheless, one can answer to the raised question : They are an infinity of solutions for $(1)$ : Simply put in $(2)$ any differentiable function and you get a solution. Even more, if you chose some convenient function $F$ , the equation $(2)$ will be solvable on closed form and you can get some explicit solutions $ξ(x,y,z)$.

EXAMPLE :

If we chose $F(X,z)=\arcsin(X)\qquad$

We are allowed to chose a function in which the second variable doesn't appear.

$ξ=\arcsin\left(x\cos(ξ)+y\sin(ξ)\right) \quad\to\quad \sin(ξ)=x\cos(ξ)+y\sin(ξ)$

$\tan(ξ)=\frac{x}{1-y} \quad\to\quad ξ(x,y,z)=\arctan\left(\frac{x}{1-y}\right)\quad$ is a solution (one among many others).

Comment: Please check again the task description, it is posed for functions $ξ$ in 3 variables $x,y,z$.

Comment: For the satisfaction of the purists, I re-edited my answer with $z$ added.

Comment: Thank you! Small and probably stupid question: how did you get (2) from $\Phi = 0$?

Comment: $\Phi(X,Y,Z)=0$ is an equation which defines the relationship between three variables $X,Y,Z$. Hence one of the variables is related to the two others. That is : $X=F(Y,Z)$ ; $Y=G(X,Z)$ ; $Z=H(X,Y)$.In the present case $\Phi$ is any function. Thus $F$ , $G$ , $H$ are any fonctions (but related one to another). Above, we used only $F$. But we could alternatively use $G$ or $H$ so leading to different forms of solutions, but equivalent one to another.